# Who are the wives/consorts of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, mahabharata, durga, ganga

Lord Shiva has been associated with Parvati/Durga, Ganga and Mohini. Can you please elaborate on these associations? Also, in the Mahabharata, didn't Ganga marry Shantanu and Mohini marry Aravan ([Iravan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iravan))? Ganga calls Bhishma 'son'. Ganesha and Skanda ([Kartikeya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya)) are also her sons. Does this make them brothers?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! According to Devi Bhagavatam, Vishnu had 3 wives Ganga, Lakshmi and Saraswati. Shantanu was incarnation of Lord Vishnu and married Ganga. Mohini marrying Avaran might be folk fair. Bhishma was Vasu in his previous birth. According to Shiva Purana, SADASHIVA (Brahman) separates into SHIVA (male energy or lord of Maya) and SHAKTI (or AdiShakti) (Prakriti or nature or MAYA). So, Shiva is supreme Purusha while Adi Shakti is Supreme Prakriti or female energy. All other goddess are different aspects of her. (1/2

Comment: Sati or Parvati is goddess of love, fertility and She was married in human form to Lord Shankara or Rudra. Durga, Kaali, and Shakti can be termed as synonymous to ADISHAKTI. Shiva Purana extols Shiva while Devi Bhagavatam extols Shakti or Devi. So, Supreme Shiva has only one consort Shakti. These words are metaphorical. Durga or Kaali is her human personification. (2/2)